how can I deactivate the code analysis for my migration files in my .net project?
I tried to do it in my .editorconfig, like so:
# lots of other single rules... 

# rule for unreachable code
dotnet_diagnostic.CS0162.severity = error

[**/Migrations/*.cs]
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.severity = none

but that doesn't work, my unreachable code in a migrations file is still shown as an error. Microsofts help page says a single rule has precedence of a general rule but is there another way? How can I exclude my migration files from code analysis?
Maybe I'm completely wrong and the way to go is not .editorconfig at all?

Can't you specify dotnet_diagnostic.CS0162.severity = none?

Think you missed a *, should be [**/Migrations /**.cs], right?

@shingo I can and that works but I want to deactivate all code analysis and not every single rule

@chris I tried that, doesn't make a difference

CSxxxx are compiler warnings, it's already surprising that they can be configured by .editorconfig.

@Chi Odd, i have several project with .editorconfigs with that setup that work. Where do you keep your editorconfig? At root level? It should be at the same level as your .sln. You can always be cheeky and add an empty .editorconfig inside your Migrations-folder. It will overwrite root level ones. "If it's stupid but it works it ain't stupid"

@chris the .editorconfig is at rootlevel. I tried creating one in my migrationsfolder but that also didnt override rootlevel configurations
